# Generic type protocol Published property

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-protocols, property-wrapper

I got x data models (struct) that conform to a protocol. I want to have in my viewModel a `@Pubished` property that represents one of those type and access each property to assign in the UI, Why is this approach not possible? I got the compiler is unable to type check.

```swift
protocol HumanProtocol {       
  associatedtype Human      
}
```

---

```swift
struct Female: HumanProtocol {
  typealias Human = Female
  var name:String
}

struct Male: HumanProtocol {
  typealias Human = Male
  var name:String
}
```

---

```swift
class HumanViewModel:ObservableObject {      
  @Published var selectedHuman: Any HumanProtocol? 
    init(selectedHuman:Any HumanProtocol) {
    self.selectedHuman = selectedHuman
  }
}
```

wanted Result:

```swift
@StateObject var humanVM = HumanViewModel(selectedHuman:Male(name:""))

TextField("Nickname", text: $humanVM.selectedHuman.name )
          .modifier(TextFieldModifier(width: 250, height: 30))
          .padding(.top))
```

Comment: That isn't how you define an `EnvironmentObject`. The `:` means you're going to tell the compiler what _type_ it is. You're trying to pass an *instance* of `HumanViewModel`. Also, `EnvironmentObject` gets injected into the hierarchy -- you don't define an instance inline like this -- you use `.environmentObject`

Comment: I know , it was a typo from another view. let me fix it, it's a ``StateObject``

Comment: What is `relationsVM`? Do you mean `humanVM`? Does it really say `Any HumanProtocol` with a capital `A`? Please make sure your question has the correct code to represent the issue -- ideally, a [mre]

Comment: Yes it is humanVM, the question has the correct code. the typos are because I don't want to paste the entire real code, but you got the idea of the problem that's the most important  @jnpdx

Comment: And you're using `Any` and not `any`?

Comment: Correct , tried both but got the same error.  @jnpdx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252461/discussion-between-david-c-and-jnpdx).

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it would be better to use a generic than trying to use `any`:

```
class HumanViewModel<T: HumanProtocol>: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var selectedHuman: T
    
    init(selectedHuman: T) {
        self.selectedHuman = selectedHuman
    }
    
}

struct Example: View {
    @StateObject private var vm = HumanViewModel(selectedHuman: Male(name: "Test"))
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $vm.selectedHuman.name)
    }
}
```

Here, the type of `HumanViewModel` can be inferred because `Male` is passed to it.